# Is the topology induced in Q by the Euclidean distance in R Discrete?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of rational number. Is the topology induced by $\mathbb{Q}$ by the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}$ Discrete?
I have said that since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then the subsets of exactly 1 rational number, {$\frac{1}{2}$}, can´t be included in an open ball of $\mathbb{R}$. But I don't like this proof as it's very flimsy.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: "I don't like this proof as it's very flimsy." It uses the very definition of induced topology. It doesn't get less flimsy.

Comment: Why do you say it is flimsy? No open ball around $\frac1  2$ is contained in $\{\frac1 2\}$ so $\{\frac1 2\}$ is not an open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ contains some rational number distinct from $0$. So, no open subset $A$ of $\Bbb Q$ to which $0$ belongs is equal to $\{0\}$ and therefore the induced topology on $\Bbb Q$ is not the discrete one.

Answer (score 0):

A down-to-earth argument:

Considering an open ball centred at the rational number $\smash{\dfrac ab}$, with radius $\varepsilon$,  do you seriously think that all numbers $\dfrac{ka+1}{kb}$ stay at a distance $\ge\varepsilon$ from $\dfrac ab$?